# Should capturing parentheses affect a separate negative lookahead?

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java. I have the following text:

```
"hyst and hy"
```

Why **(hy)(?![a-z])** returns two "hy"s. The idea is to match any "hy" that is not followed by any character between a-z.

If I do **hy(?![a-z])** (hy without parentheses) it works (finds only the second "hy") but I don't understand why if I use parentheses (hy) in the RegEx it matches the first "hy" in hyst

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem in your regex.  Please post your test code.  Perhaps the problem is a subtle mistake in how you're using the regex.

Comment: please show the codes about `returns` two "hy"s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a capture group you obtain two results, the first is the whole pattern and the second the capture group. The first `hy` has never been matched.

If you remove the parenthesis, you obtain only that match the whole pattern.